# Bower Error angular-bootstrap3-datepicker - ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, bower, bower-install

Getting the Econflict error on installing angular-bootstrap3-datepicker

```js
bower angular-bootstrap3-datepicker#*           cached git://github.com/benzen/angular-bootstrap3-datepicker.git#1.0.3
bower angular-bootstrap3-datepicker#*         validate 1.0.3 against git://github.com/benzen/angular-bootstrap3-datepicker.git#*
bower bootstrap#3.3.0                           cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.0
bower bootstrap#3.3.0                         validate 3.3.0 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.0
bower bootstrap3-datetimepicker#3.1.3           cached git://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker.git#3.1.3
bower bootstrap3-datetimepicker#3.1.3         validate 3.1.3 against git://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker.git#3.1.3
bower angular#1.3.0                             cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.0
bower angular#1.3.0                           validate 1.3.0 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.0
bower momentjs#2.4.0                            cached git://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.4.0
bower momentjs#2.4.0                          validate 2.4.0 against git://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.4.0
bower font-awesome#4.0.3                        cached git://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.0.3
bower font-awesome#4.0.3                      validate 4.0.3 against git://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.0.3
bower jquery#1.11.1                             cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.11.1
bower jquery#1.11.1                           validate 1.11.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.11.1
bower moment#>=2.8.0                            cached git://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.10.6
bower moment#>=2.8.0                          validate 2.10.6 against git://github.com/moment/moment.git#>=2.8.0
bower angular#~1.4.4                            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.6
bower angular#~1.4.4                          validate 1.4.6 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.4.4
bower jquery#~2.1.4                             cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.4
bower jquery#~2.1.4                           validate 2.1.4 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~2.1.4
bower                                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
```

My bower.json

```js
{
  "name": "ReportApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A JIRA Report App",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.4",
    "angular-route": "~1.4.4",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "underscore": "~1.8.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
"ignoredDependencies": ["angular"]
```

to your bower.cc file